# Make my SQL query dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

My table has an ID int (PK) and then col1- col32 strings. The value in my columns are different from time too time. Sometimes 10 is filled sometimes all and so on. Could i make this SQL dynamic so i dont have to fill it up with all my 32 columns?

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  ID,
                Column_Name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY col) row_num,
                val
        FROM tPivot A
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Column_Name AS COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tPivot' ) B
        ON A.ID = B.ORDINAL_POSITION - 1
        UNPIVOT
        (
            val for col in (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
        ) unpvt
    ) A
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(val) FOR column_name IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
    ) pvt
)

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
            row_num,
            coalesce(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) val
    FROM cte
) A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(val) FOR ID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) pvt
```

Comment: Provide SQL Fiddle with sample data

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7cfb/3 This is how it Looks like, Need the right part too be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

great.
for building the IDs for `PIVOT` part of the query (I mean for  `([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])`) use:

```
DECLARE @IDP AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @IDP = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ID) 
                    from (select distinct row_num as ID from CTE) q
                    group by q.ID
                    order by q.ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

and now you can use it within `dynamic sql`:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql='
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  ID,
                Column_Name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY col) row_num,
                val
        FROM tPivot A
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Column_Name AS COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''tPivot'' ) B
        ON A.ID = B.ORDINAL_POSITION - 1
        UNPIVOT
        (
            val for col in (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
        ) unpvt
    ) A
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(val) FOR column_name IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
    ) pvt
)

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
            row_num,
            coalesce(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) val
    FROM cte
) A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(val) FOR ID IN ('+@IDP+')
) pvt'
EXEC(@sql)
```

The [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7cfb/16) based on the schema and your query in the fiddle demo you mentioned in comments.

**NOTE:** maybe your original query could be more optimized, I just tried to say how to make it for using with dynamic sql for all ids(rows)

Comment: You are welcome, _can't get it to work :(_  what's the problem?

Comment: I dont know where to paste your solution and where to make some changes :S Sorry im a beginner. This is the orginial in fiddle. As i said the values is dynamic and can be different each times. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7cfb/3

Comment: Ok, so let me to review it

Comment: @user2210516, what happened, I'm waiting for a feedback if not it not works for you. I have to go.